# IndexOutOfBoundsException in ByteBuffer's comparison java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, bytebuffer

I have a problem with this method

```
private static boolean getBlocks(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {
    FileChannel channel1 = new FileInputStream(file1).getChannel();
    FileChannel channel2 = new FileInputStream(file2).getChannel();
    int SIZE = (int) Math.min((8192), channel1.size());
    int point = 0;
    MappedByteBuffer buffer1 = channel1.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel1.size());
    MappedByteBuffer buffer2 = channel2.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel2.size());
    byte [] bytes1 = new byte[SIZE];
    byte [] bytes2 = new byte[SIZE];
    while (point < channel1.size() - SIZE) {
        buffer1.get(bytes1, point, SIZE);
        buffer2.get(bytes2, point, SIZE);
        if (!compareBlocks(bytes1, bytes2)) {
            return false;
        }
        point += SIZE;
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean compareBlocks (byte[] bytes1, byte[] bytes2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.length; i++) {
        if (bytes1[i] != bytes2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In a result I caught IndexOutOfBoundsException in while loop.
How can I get around this problem and compare two files by blocks?

Comment: Err, `ByteBuffer` defines `.equals()` so why don't you just use that?

Comment: Where / what `IndexOutOfBoundsException` do you get? I don't see any place that could produce one.

Comment: Oh, if i try to return buffer1.equals(buffer2) i get java.io.IOException: Map failed

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    - at java.nio.Buffer.checkBounds(Buffer.java:567)
    - at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:265)
    - and than at buffer1.get(bytes1, point, SIZE);

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... it has to crap.

You create a byte array with 'SIZE' length and access it's position with point var which increments with 'SIZE' vallue.

For example:

```
int SIZE = 10; 
int point = 0;     
while( point < channel.size() - SIZE ){
   buffer1.get(bytes1, point, SIZE);
   // Your logic here
   point += SIZE;
}
```

When you do the above, SIZE vallue increments enourmously and you try to access the byte array with point position which will have a higher vallue than it's size.

So, your logic to access the array position is wrong. As the error line says, you're accessing and index out of bounds( higher than the limit ).

I hope I could help you.